# The toggleClass duration doesn't work on pseudo-elements

Tags: jquery, css

It seems the duration value of the toggleClass method is not working when I use it on pseudo-elements :after and :before. Btw, the toggle works.

You can test it in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scitech/9rks7rwf/).

jQuery:

```
$('p').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('special', 500);
});
```

CSS:

```
p:before {
   content:"foo";
   color: red;
   cursor:pointer;
}
   p.special:before {
   content:"bar";
}
```

I would like to know if there's a way to make it work. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) - toggleClass has no duration value. The second value is a boolean switch

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair thanks for this advice. To be honest I used the same schema of other titles when I wrote mine. But I will know it for the next time.

Comment: @Collett89 Actually it has according to jQuery page: http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/ Now I'm confused, then.

Comment: @Gerard JQuery and JQueryUI are different libraries - if you add JQueryUI you will be able to use that version of toggleClass to add the delay you are looking for

Comment: @Collett89 Oh I see. Thank you. That explains why it was not working: because I use JQuery, not JQueryUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`toggleClass`** have doesn't contain duration parameter. if you want animate feature use jquery **`.animate()`**

the syntax is `$(selector).toggleClass(classname,function(index,currentclass),switch)`;

`classname` Required. Specifies one or more class names to add or remove. To specify several classes, separate the class names with a space
function(index,currentclass)    Optional. Specifies a function that returns one or more class names to add/remove

`index` - Returns the index position of the element in the set
`currentclass` - Returns current class name of selected elements

`switch`    Optional. A Boolean value specifying if the class should only be added (true), or only be removed (false)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me be more specific, the animation is not a change of position, is a transition when it changes the icon; one icon replaces the other slowly (500 miliseconds), and the new one is in the same place.